# Get the version of an app programatically in iOS

Tags: ios, version

Is there a way to get the version of other app(outside of my control) in my app? I know it may not comply with iOS sandbox rules, but is it possible to do so? And what if i can control the "other app"? All the apps mentioned will not be published on App Store, only just for our own guys.

Comment: In theory, yes.  You just need to extract it out of the other app's plist.  However, as you noted, this will not work in a non-jailbroken environment.  Even inside a jailbroken environment you might need to move your app to the Applications folder.

Comment: are you coding *both* applications, or only just one application and the other application is outside of your control?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes, the other app is outside of my control.

Comment: @borrrden, it is for non-jailbreak environment, but my app will not be published on App Store, so no concern of apple will reject it. So there is really no directly way to do so?

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case.  The sandbox will prevent you from interacting with any other applications, even with private APIs.

Comment: @borrrden calling a private api, via a category is not prevented.

Comment: @AlexWien, it's all for business requirement, actually the "other app" are all develop by our own company. All the apps are for our employee only.

Comment: @AlexWien, so, if I coding both apps, then I can get the version of an app by calling a private api?

Comment: @PercSun . No, Wwith private API I meant a private API of Apple, accessible but not documented. if you coded both apps then you only could send the app version via IP to your server, which forwards it to your other app.

Comment: @AlexWien No private API will allow you to do it either.  The sandbox runs outside of he apps controls and limits its access to its own sandbox.

Comment: @borrrden yes, i have not told, that one can use a private API to get the app version. i said only that one can call private API whatever they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and there is no reason to get it.
(Of course questions and answers asumes by default a non-jailbreaked environment)